# How do I call the dashboard's sortable javascript in a plugin page?

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, sort

I want to create a multi-column sortable widget area in a plugin's settings page. In order to test this, I started by directly copying my dashboard's HTML content from `<div id="dashboard-widgets-wrap">` (including everything inside it). I got a nice rendering of my dashboard's widgets along with the auto-column system.

My problem is that I cannot call the script that makes these widgets sortable (`jquery-ui-sortable`). Furthermore, I would like to get the order saved somewhere, is there another script for this? Where does the Dashboard natively save the Dashboard widget order?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `manage edit-post type columns` kind of hooks help you with sort-able columns. Refer: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_edit-post_type_columns. Is that you are after? Else you should explain your problem more clearly!

Comment: Why can't you call jquery-ui-sortable?